# Cannot import name "ResolveInfo" Error attempting to run after installing Saleor python django CMS

Tags: python, django, windows, azure, saleor

Hi Am Attempting to install the latest version of Saleor Django based ecommerce CMS to a windows VM on AzUre. I followed  the Saleor installation instruction  steps based on the provided requirement.txt file and the Azure instructions to setup up a web app.

I have completed  the install twice and each time when I attempt to run Saleor I receive this error below. I have scanned the  Internet and found this [link](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/546)

Just wondering if :

- any one can explain the statement  "had a folder called graphql in my path" I have no idea what this statement means since I am only a beginner orogrammer. [Replacing  the file with "graphql-core>=2.0.dev" makes no difference]
- any one can give me some diagnostic steps that I could go through to help me find  the  reason for the error.  Any help appreciated.

> ```
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "run_waitress_server.py", line 9, in <module>
>         application = get_wsgi_application()
>       File "D:\home\python364x64\Lib\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
>         django.setup(set_prefix=False)
>       File "D:\home\python364x64\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
>         apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
>       File "D:\home\python364x64\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 89, in populate
>         app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
>       File "D:\home\python364x64\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
>         module = import_module(entry)
>       File "E:\A\_work\79\b\source_packages\python.3.6.4\tools\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
>       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
>       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
>       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
>       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
>       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
>       File "D:\home\python364x64\Lib\site-packages\graphene_django\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
>         from .types import (
>       File "D:\home\python364x64\Lib\site-packages\graphene_django\types.py", line 4, in <module>
>         from graphene import Field
>       File "D:\home\python364x64\Lib\site-packages\graphene\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
>         from .types import (
>       File "D:\home\python364x64\Lib\site-packages\graphene\types\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
>         from graphql import ResolveInfo
>     ImportError: cannot import name 'ResolveInfo'
> ```

Comment: have you in your project some folder or file with name `graphql` ?

Comment: Thanks  for reply Yes the saleor complete package has  a folder named graphql but given this folder has been present for the last 4 releases I had assumed renaming the folder  was not a step worth trying  but willing to try if that is the suggestion. Chris

Comment: @zimdero  I have since completed a new install of Saleor into Python Tools for Visual Studio (PTVS) on a local windows machine running windows 10 just to eliminate Azure from the equation. Using the testing environment I have 1) renamed the Saleor folder named graphql  to graphqlOLD 2) alternatively tried renaming Lib/Site- package: graphql  folder to graphqlOLD. Given the limited docs on this issue on the Internet. I simply at a loss as to what to do next. Is there some guidance on what steps I could go through to narrow down the problem using the PTVS debugger?